# Strange error "Object is possibly 'undefined'" on a dictionary

Tags: typescript

In the following code, why does the `stopsDict["first"].directions.push("test");` line pass the check but not the `stopsDict[stopName].directions.push("test");` one ?

```js
interface StopsDict {
  [key: string]: Stops;
}

interface Stops {
  directions?: string[];
}

let stopsDict: StopsDict = { 
  first: {
    directions: []
  },
  second: {}
};

if (Array.isArray(stopsDict["first"].directions)) {
  stopsDict["first"].directions.push("test"); //OK
}

let stopName = "first";
if (Array.isArray(stopsDict[stopName].directions)) {
  stopsDict[stopName].directions.push("test"); //error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: Object is possibly 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068390/typescript-object-is-possibly-undefined) (the second answer there is better than the accepted one)

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed the same problem. Bottom line : I need to write something like `(stopsDict[stopName].directions as string[]).push("test")` event if I just checked that `stopsDict[stopName].directions` is an array the line before.

Answer (score -1):

Because `stopsDict[name].directions` could, in theory, be `null`. You could tell TS that you know better, and accept all responsibility if it isn't:

```
stopsDict[name].directions!.push("test")
```

For a non-toy example, you would want to introduce checks that make sure the preconditions are satisfied, rather than brute-force through the type-checker.

See more [in docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#nullable-types).

Specifically, this does not raise an error:

```
let dirs = stopsDict[stopName].directions;
if (Array.isArray(dirs)) {
  dirs.push("test");
}
```

Comment: I've edited the code to show that the errors persists even if I check that `stopsDict[stopName].direction is an array` ( thus `stopName` can't be null).

Comment: TS doesn't remember the check from one expression to the next. `let dirs = stopsDict[stopName].directions; if (Array.isArray(dirs)) { dirs.push...` does not raise an error.