# Proper Typescript syntax for accessing a possibly not-yet-created dynamic key:value pair

Tags: typescript

I have a class that has a `private` object property with dynamic keys.

*map.ts*

```
class BobController {
    private bobMap?: {[key: string]: BobSource}
}
```

Later, I have a function that will add properties to that object under a given key, if that key doesn't exist.

*map.ts*

```
getBobLayer(bobStatus: BobStatusType) {
    if (!this.bobMap[`${bobStatus}`]) {
      this.bobMap[`${bobStatus}`] = new BobSource({ features: [] })
    } 
    return this.bobMap[`${bobStatus}`]
    
}
```

With the above code, I get the error

```
125:10 Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

For both my `if` check as well as my assignment/creation line.

Using other [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined) answers, I tried changing my code to

```
    if (!this?.bobMap[`_${bobStatus}`]) {
```

Adding the `?` optional chaining parameter. However, I still get the same error. Another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068662/2590119) recommended using a fallback with the `||` operator, so I tried as follows:

```
    if (!this?.bobMap || {}[`_${bobStatus}`]) {
```

Now, I have the error

```
125:44 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
```

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

However, beyond here the syntax gets too messy, or beyond my understanding. I tried things like

```
    if (!this?.bobMap || {} as {[key: string] [`_${bobStatus}`])
```

but am getting syntax errors.

One solution is to simply make `bobMap` not an optional `private` property, and initialize it in the constructor, but I'm now very curious what I would need to do if that weren't an option.

**What's the typescript syntax to optionally chain a possibly-undefined, dynamic-key-accessed object on a class?**

Comment: You have to initialize it to an empty object, otherwise this will always throw `this.bobMap[\`${bobStatus}\`] = new BobSource({ features: [] })`

Comment: Ah, as I feared then, I must initialize in the constructor (or wherever)? as in     `this.bobMap = {} as {[key: string]: BobSource}`

Comment: No, just `private bobMap: {[key: string]: BobSource} = {}`