# TypeScript Error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' when the object is clearly defined

Tags: typescript

I'm getting `ts object is possibly undefined` on the line `groupedImports[id].push(item)`, with `groupedImports[id]` underlined.

I test that `hits` exists and has length > 0 prior to this clause, and create `groupedImports[]` if needed.

I don't understand why ts thinks `groupedImports[id]` might be undefined.

```
// Dictionary is from @reduxjs/redux-toolkit

interface ImportError {
  text: string,
  args: string,
}

interface Import {
  status: string,
  "@import_id": string,
  "@import_time": Date,
  "@import_file": string,
  errors: Array<ImportError>
}

let groupedImports: Dictionary<Import[]> = {}

hits.forEach( (item) => {

    const id = item['@import_id']
    if (id) {
      if (!(id in groupedImports)) {
        groupedImports[id] = [];
      }
      groupedImports[id].push(item);
    }
  })
```

See [@reduxjs/redux-toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit) for the [Dictionary type](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/8565fc25803beedc1032d67473c6b448da588405/packages/toolkit/src/entities/models.ts#L19-L31).

Comment: what's `Import`?

Comment: added Import definition

Comment: This seems to be OK in the playground, for TypeScript v3.3+ at least: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=28&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/PQKgBAhgJlCmVjgYwDYQE4QC4EsD2AdgM5gjABQWAngA6xgAiOSuhGVAPACoB8YAvGABKsJHnRQORLOhwEA5gBowvANzlkadPTHEsYABY4sRAFxgAkgFsa4rAG0AuutBhYBBGXLk5WWOgAzCCR6a1t0LABRdHRxMABvcjAwPwAPLHNpWQVFJMh0eTMwLLklcgBfb19-IJDLGzsEvOlsAFcikpy8gCIAARwGiIB9HChuzJlS3OTgYDAAOkWK7xRYfXlY1rooMLsiphZ8AnYOXYinPkF4yvIjE3mA8UjggwAKMFfjWCsASgE+RJ5ZK6aRgUYCMF+Kz2ADk-UGWBGUBhjiBYICH1Gf0SyVx6I+AEJPgg5GANngtvAziYfti0XjyZSdgiiPZRo4IU51HjkpUeWTNttqaz2fMaO03l9ftzcXywOUfkA)

Comment: Didn't know about the playground; thanks for that! I notice you defined Dictionary. I have `import { Dictionary } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";'. I changed to that and it resolved. Must be something I don't understand in redux toolkit...THANKS!!

Comment: You're welcome! I added an answer with a little more detail, now that I know what's going on. For the future I recommend _against_ editing the solution into your question, because at this point future answerers would have _no_ hope in reproducing the problem as you'd had it. (I'll revert your change, just so it's clearer to future readers.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeff Bowman, something about the definition of Dictionary I was using (from react toolkit)..

Adding `type Dictionary<T> = Record<string, T>;` resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Redux Toolkit's [Dictionary](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/8565fc25803beedc1032d67473c6b448da588405/packages/toolkit/src/entities/models.ts#L19-L31) is declared to be much like Record, except that the values are possibly `undefined`. That's why you're encountering that problem, and why my naïve attempt at defining Dictionary didn't reproduce it.

```
if (id) {
  if (!(id in groupedImports)) {
    groupedImports[id] = [];
  }
  groupedImports[id].push(item);
}
```

In this code, you can establish that `groupedImports[id]` will never be `undefined` by the time `push` runs, but TypeScript is still prepared for the possibility that `groupedImports[id]` is `undefined`. Notably, this is true *even if you remove the `if` guard and unconditionally set the value to `[]`*, as in [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/PQKgBAhgJlCmVjgYwDYQE4QC4EsD2AdgM5gjABQWAngA6xgAiOSuhGVAPACoB8YAvGABKsJHnRQORLOhwEA5gBowXMAB8wAVwJwAZnPg8A3OWRp09McSxgAFjixEAXGACSAWxrisAbQC6JqBgsDqkFORyWLDouhBI9B5e6FgAoujo4mAA3uRgYFEAHlgu0rIKirmQ6PLOYKVySuQAvuQRBFExcQme3tmV0tiatfXllQBEAAI4PckA+jhQYyUyDRV5wMBgAHQ7za0osDbyGZp0UInetUws+ATsHBfJ-nyCWS3k9o5buuIpcbYACjAAIcsHcAEoBHwcnk8lZpGAFgJEVF3D4AORTGZYeZQdF+Sp5HC6YELSEw2F5Y54U7wR6OHwLPzI-wmSlUk5nelERlQPxbGhDQGgiFs2EtPJNcFAA).

As alluded to in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068670/1426891) and described by MartinJohns in [microsoft/TypeScript#41612](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41612#issuecomment-731345701):

> Type narrowing does not occur for indexed access forms `e[k]` where `k` is not a literal.

Other than using `Record<string, Import[]>` directly or redefining Dictionary to be non-undefined in all keys, you can use a [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) (postfix `!`) to tell TypeScript not to worry about the possibility of `undefined`.

```
groupedImports[id]!.push(item);
//                ^
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/PQKgBAhgJlCmVjgYwDYQE4QC4EsD2AdgM5gjABQWAngA6xgAiOSuhGVAPACoB8YAvGABKsJHnRQORLOhwEA5gBowXMAB8wAVwJwAZnPg8A3OWRp09McSxgAFjixEAXGACSAWxrisAbQC6JqBgsDqkFORyWLDouhBI9B5e6FgAoujo4mAA3uRgYFEAHlgu0rIKirmQ6PLOYKVySuQAvuQRBFExcQme3tmV0tiatfXllQBEAAI4PckA+jhQYyUyDRV5wMBgAHQ7za0osDbyGZp0UInetUws+ATsHBfJ-nyCWS3k9o5buuIpcbYACjAAIcsHcAEoBHwcpU8lZpGAFgJEVF3D4AORTGZYeZQdF+WGI3TAhaQnJ5ClE4EAQhBCDkYGOeFO8EejnBZMJlKZLPO2KIPgWfmR-hMlLyLXFjJOZzZAqF1K2NCGgNBELFFMlYCa4KAA)